# For python is there a way to print variables scope from context where exception happens?

Tags: python, exception

Is there a way to print variables scope from context where exception happens?

For example:

```
def f():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    1/0

try:
    f()
except:
    pass # here I want to print something like "{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"
```

Comment: What does "to print variables scope" mean?  Could you give an example?

Comment: That's what the `except` clause is for.  Please provide some code to illustrate why you're not printing things in the `except` clause.

Comment: I mean to print all variables in the scope of exception.

Comment: I've added an example in description

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the function `sys.exc_info()` to get the last exception that occurred in the current thread in you except clause. This will be a tuple of exception type, exception instance and traceback. The traceback is a linked list of frame. This is what is used to print the backtrace by the interpreter. It does contains the local dictionnary.

So you can do:

```
import sys

def f():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    1/0

try:
    f()
except:
    exc_type, exc_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    if tb is not None:
        prev = tb
        curr = tb.tb_next
        while curr is not None:
            prev = curr
            curr = curr.tb_next
        print prev.tb_frame.f_locals
```

Comment: Amazing.  This is one of the most satisfying SO answers I've had the pleasure of using.

Answer (score 7):

You have to first extract traceback, in your example something like this would print it:

```
except:
    print sys.exc_traceback.tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals
```

I'm not sure about the tb_next, I would guess you have to go through the complete traceback, so something like this (untested):

```
except:
    tb_last = sys.exc_traceback
    while tb_last.tb_next:
        tb_last = tb_last.tb_next
    print tb_last.tb_frame.f_locals
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're looking for [locals()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) and [globals()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals)?

Comment: I saw it before my question but it can't get context variables of exception. I don't know how to use it in example above.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. In your example code, you wouldn't be able to get the context of the function `f` using these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, there are 2 general best practices.

**Just print the variables with minimal code edits**

Have a look at some related packages. For simple usage you might pick [traceback-with-variables](https://pypi.org/project/traceback-with-variables) (`pip install traceback-with-variables`), here is it's postcard

[image]

Or try [tbvaccine](https://pypi.org/project/tbvaccine/), or [better-exceptions](https://pypi.org/project/better-exceptions/), or [any other package](https://pypi.org/search/?q=print%20varaibles%20on%20traceback)

**Programmatically access variables to use them in your code**

Use `inspect` module

```
except ... as ...:
    x = inspect.trace()[-1][0].f_locals['x']
```